# Why should I care to set up SSH for VNC?

Tags: ssh, security, vnc

Assuming that the content of the screen I operate on doesn't contain any sensitive information, does tunneling VNC (TightVNC) session through SSH makes my VNC server less prone to attacks and potential gain of the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the flavor and version of the VNC server and client there could be several weaknesses in security:

- password authentication is transmitted in cleartext so that the password could be sniffed
- password length is limited so the authentication strength is limited
- data (picture) are trasmitted in cleartext so they can be sniffed

See [VNC security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing#Security) and [Using VNC with SSH](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/vnc/sshvnc.html).

### TightVNC

Particularly TightVNC has limitations in authentication. According to the [FAQ](http://www.tightvnc.com/faq.php#howsecure) it has password limited to only 8 characters and uses a weak cipher (DES 56 bit) for authentication. The picture data is not encrypted at all.

In fact TightVNC can automatically use SSH and TightVNC Java Viewer has SSH encryption built-in to overcome the security limitations.